# Senchatouch 2 with phonegap store not running

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I created an app with Sencha-touch it works perfectly and every thing is right

but i needed to add phone-gap  every thing is well and working

```
 except (stores  they are not running)
```

i tried different versions of both Phone-gap and android and the same result (store not running)

```
what should i do ?
```

Comment: are you talking about sencha touch stores ?

Comment: yes i talk about sencha touch stores

Comment: they are working fine without  adding phonegap

Comment: phonegap is nothing to do with sencha stores.. may be you configured phonegap wrongly.. any error ?

Comment: i notice this error but i don't know it is related to this problem or no Unknown chromim error:0

Comment: i think the http request not fire

Comment: i tried to log the store it returns to me object so it is loading

Comment: i tried to log the records they didn't return any thing so the store is loaded fine but no http request

Comment: did you testing in chrome ?

Comment: no  errors appear and the cross origin is fine because the app is working and published without phone gap and works fine